# Unable to locate the RAM2 tag in Non-paged Pool

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory-leaks

I have figured out my computer has a memory leak, and a 14.5 GB Non-Paged pool:

[image: Task Manager Shot]

I have tried to run poolmon.exe and it came up with this, and I suspect it is the "RAM2" tag to be the cause:

[image: poolmon.exe Shot]

I tried to find the tag in the pooltag.txt file and used stirngs, but still unable to find it:

[image: pooltag.txt Shot]

[image: cmd strings Shot]

I am now having no idea on what should I do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From
[Finding Memory Leaks with PoolMon](https://medium.com/@clintcolding/finding-memory-leaks-with-poolmon-3da80e479040):

> Once you’ve found a suspect process, note the Tag assigned to it, in
> my case its MFeS. You can now use the tag to determine the specific
> driver(s) it’s associated with:
>
> ```
> Set-Location "C:\Windows\System32\drivers"
> Select-String -Path *.sys -Pattern "MFeS" -CaseSensitive | Select-Object FileName -Unique
> ```

In your case, use the following PowerShell commands:

```
Set-Location "C:\Windows\System32\drivers"
Select-String -Path *.sys -Pattern "RAM2" -CaseSensitive | Select-Object FileName -Unique
```

Comment: IT works!! MANY THANKSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!